# error: package android.v7.app does not exist

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Hi there stackoverflow community, hope you can help!

Im using udacity to learn android development and I have ran into a problem. there are a few errors that have come up:

```
error: package android.v7.app does not exist    
error: cannot find symbol class AppCompatActivity   
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype  
error: cannot find symbol variable super    
error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)    
error: cannot find symbol class openNumbersList 
error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)
```

Everything was working fine but I was following a tutorial and noticed that my imports in my Main Activity didn't match with what was on the tutorial so I changed:

"import..."

to

import android.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

also even before this, "AppCompatActivity" was in red:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void openNumbersList(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, openNumbersList.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.miwok"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'

}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Use this : compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1"  in build.gradle

Comment: Post your complete `MainActivity` code here. I think know how to solve it

Comment: done, Abner Escocio has come to save the day!!

Comment: Siros that didn't work just said compile is obsolete. I was under the impression I need to use implementation now.... Abner help please haha

Comment: @AbnerEscocio  forgot to @ you... appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: Thanks bro for @. Now post your gradle file. I know how to solve it

Comment: @AbnerEscocio here you go mate

Answer (score 0):

Try your gradle as follow

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.miwok"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

}
```

I think that above code solve your issue

Comment: I've given that a go @AbnerEscocio and it give me the same java compiler errors as above :(

Answer (score -2):

Anyone who faces this problem has to revise the coding of padding and alignment attributes.
The fault is simple.
All you have to do is to be careful with the attributes specifying.

Comment: Welcome to SO Zubair. Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write a good answer.